# POP3 + Mail client = no new messages on server (despite having new messages on server)

Tags: email, thunderbird, smtp, pop3

I'm using Thunderbird.  I've used it forever.  Today I noticed mail wasn't being delivered for about 2 days; after checking the usual suspects and confirming I see new mail in my server account's /var/mail inbox (via tail -f and sending myself a message from a third party), I noticed Thunderbird would quickly say no new messages on server.

I then installed outlook and tried checking the mail.  Same thing.  Nothing is downloaded.

I run an older postfix for SMTP and courier pop for the pop daemon.  Thunderbird is set to store messages on server until I delete them (the mail file is a healthy 2.17GB).

Anyone ever encounter this?  Any ideas on cause or resolution?  I thought pop was fairly dumb server-side, but this is perplexing me.

Comment: Try to execute the "Repair" function on the Inbox in Thunderbird (button in properties dialog of Inbox folder). Also make sure Thunderbird really connects successfully to your mail server and check if the server really announces the new messages (check using different mail program or directly talk via telnet to the POP3 server).

Answer (score 0):

I realized it must be a problem with the server's mail file and discovered that there was a missing *From* header (or a few too many newlines between a message end and From: tag) thanks to a Thunderbird error: *Unable to process From lines (envelopes), change recognition modes*

I ended up using the command `csplit userfile '/^Date: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 08:59:38 -0500$/'` based on the last message I received in the inbox.

Once I reconstructed it properly (putting the appropriate *From:* at the top of the file) and replaced the inbox file on the server, I was then able to pull the mail down.

I've since zero'd out the server's mailbox and restarted postfix.